# How to track all the web request in my machine?

Tags: java

I tried using Muffin's web proxy to record the url's that were hit in the browser.
I am able to track the internet request like google.com,stackoverflow etc.,
But, was unable to track the intranet request like the one which does not need internet. I am not sure how intranet works because those request for the url were not being tracked.
Is there a way to track those request as well(intranet urls).

1) I am able to track the weburls because i am redirecting all the request to the socket i had created in java.But setting it up as a proxy in the settings.

2) Usually intranet sites do not rely on the proxy servers. it will directly communicate though dns server.How to make those request also to go through my socket ?

**Note** I am trying to achieve it using JAVA sockets.

Comment: You will have to give us more information. As it is right now it is very unclear what exactly you want to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it. Please edit your question to include additional details and you'll have a much higher chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: 1) I am able to track the weburls because i am redirecting all the request to the socket i had created in java.But setting it up as a proxy in the settings.2) Usually intranet sites do not rely on the proxy servers. it will directly communicate though dns server.How to make those request also to go through my socket ?

Comment: @mhlz did you understand what i want ?

Comment: It is much clearer now, yes. That is why I upvoted your question again.

Comment: @mhlz thanks. how to track the request to intranet ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a windows application called FIDDLER.... It can track all type of inbound and outbound connections...

Comment: I need it as a java program.

Comment: You want to make a whole java program for it (as a software) or you just want it for checking the inbound and outbound connections ????

Comment: just checking the inbound and outbound.